# How to call a method of the base class from the inherited class in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have initial class(class module) `CSVUtiltiy` with the following function:

```
Public Sub fillData(ByRef d As Dictionary, ByRef TmpAr() As String)
End Sub
```

and I have inherited class(class module) `CSVUtilityInherited`, with overwritten function:

```
Implements csvUtility
Private Sub csvUtility_fillData(d As Scripting.IDictionary, TmpAr() As String)
End Sub
```

How can I call from `csvUtility_fillData` function of the base class `fillData`?

Comment: Interfaces cannot have implemented methods.

Comment: It is not an interface it is a base class.

Comment: in VBA, there's no inheritance *of code*. You can only implement interfaces (like pure abstract classes in C++, but ALL methods pure virtual). Inheritance of code can only be made using *delegation*.

Comment: Do you mean I have to aggregate some another class so I can reuse same code in both classes?

Comment: You embed an instance of the base class in the derived class and wrap explicitly the methods you want to delegate to the base class. While wrapping, you can change the methods that you want to behave differently.

Comment: So If I have class A and B is inherited from A, I should create an instance of A in B class? But then comes another question can I not overwrite all methods of A but only part of it, because "MS-ACCESS" ask me to overwrite all the methods?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135951/discussion-between-light-harut-and-a-s-h).

Comment: To achieve inheritance you should at least wrap/rewrite all the public methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I got it.

Answer (score -2):

=(

I think there is no way to call base sub.

VBA only implements interfaces. So, you must write realisation of all public functions, subs and properties.

When you implement "class", vba just implements its "hidden" interface (interface of this class). not more =(

Vba use QueryInterface calls to read declaration of all base-class members

So, you need to make your own realization of all base "class" members

=(((